# Very dumb error message: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;

Tags: javascript, html, syntax, syntax-error

I got a very dumb error mssage:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token;

I can not see where the syntax is wrong:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var start = $.superscollorama();            
        start.addTween('#windSection', Tweenmax.from($('#windSection'), .25, {css:{backgroundColor:'blue'}});    
});
```

Comment: You missed a closing bracket `)` on line 3.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a simple typo.

Comment: Well that fixed it thanks for noticing :)

Comment: use a syntax checker instead of posting code here... dumb message, dumb mistake => easy fix

Answer (score 4):

There's no prizes for putting everything on one line:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var start = $.superscollorama();            
        start.addTween(
            '#windSection', 
            Tweenmax.from(
                $('#windSection'), 
                .25, 
                {
                    css:{
                        backgroundColor:'blue'
                    }
                }
            ) //missed this one
        );
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you missed a `)` in line 3:

```
start.addTween(
  '#windSection',
  Tweenmax.from(
     $('#windSection'),
     .25,
     {
        css: {
          backgroundColor:'blue'
        }
     }
   )
); // <<<<
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var start = $.superscollorama();
        start.addTween('#windSection', 
            Tweenmax.from($('#windSection'), 
                .25, 
                {
                    css: { backgroundColor: 'blue' }
                }
            );
        ); // this one
    });
```

Comment: Wrong, You now added a superfluous closing brace }

Comment: Posted wrong example, sorry. Fixed